# Updating Craft Produced Fatal Error.What now?

Tags: updating, auto-updates, updates, manual-updates

Just tried updating craft from version 2.4.2669 to the latest version 2.4.2702 unfortunately it threw a fatal error with the following error message:

> Status: OK
>
> Response: 
>  **Fatal error**: Out of memory (allocated
>   33030144) (tried to allocate 41 bytes) in
>   **/homepages/3/d272256762/htdocs/crafttest/craft/app/framework/db/CDbCommand.php**
>   on line **518**

So I then tried to manually install it by uploading the app folder. Clicked through on the update databases it started working, but again threw the same error.

The site is on a shared server so I can not do much regarding memory limits.

So now I have no CMS and no frontend what can I do to rectify this problem to either rollback to the previous version or update to the newer one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How big is your database? It could be that Craft is failing to backup your database as part of the update process because it is running out of memory.

Try setting the [`backupDbOnUpdate`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#backupDbOnUpdate) config setting to `false` and running the update again.

Comment: That's likely it, though regardless of database size, the current `memory_limit` is `32M`, so I'd bump that up regardless. Once you start any image processing (transforms, etc.) you'll hit the same error.

Comment: Cheers @steverowling that worked a treat. Yes database is pretty large so obviously what was causing the issue.

Comment: @bradbell good point would do this with a non-shared server unfortunately hands are tied on this one. But it's only a play around test site so not an issue!

Comment: @Lettie Ahh, missed that part in your original post. My bad.